# Why does std::max return by const&?

Tags: c++, reference, return, max, constants

I'd like to find the max `Foo` and call `inc()` on it, which is a non-const method.  Of course in finding the max, I don't want to create any copies or moves, i.e. I don't want `Foo foo = std::max(foo1, foo2)`.  I tried writing my own max, and g++ insists I return a const&.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(int x) : x_(x) { std::cout << "const" << std::endl; }
  Foo(const Foo& foo) : x_(foo.x_) { std::cout << "copy const" << std::endl; }
  Foo(Foo&& foo) : x_(foo.x_) { std::cout << "move const" << std::endl; }
  bool operator< (const Foo& foo) const { return x_ < foo.x_; }
  bool operator> (const Foo& foo) const { return x_ > foo.x_; }
  void inc() { ++x_; }
  int x_;
};

/*
 * Doesn't compile.  Must return const T& or must accept non-const T&
 *
template<typename T>
inline T& my_max(const T& f1, const T& f2)
{
  return f1 > f2 ? f1 : f2;
}
*
*/

int main()
{
  Foo foo1(6);      
  Foo foo2(7);      
  Foo& foo = std::max(foo1, foo2); //Doesn't compile.  Must be const Foo&. But then next line fails
  foo.inc();
  std::cout << foo.x_ << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It returns a const reference to avoid unnecessary copying, because it predates rvalue references and move semantics. It would probably be defined differently if creating it today, e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2199.html

Comment: Another option would be to add `Foo copy() const& { return *this; }` so you can write `std::max(fooA,fooB).copy().inc();`. Sometimes it's a pain that the copy constructor has no name.

Comment: You already know one answer: Your comment said *"...or must accept non-const T& ..."*. Your two variables, `foo1` and `foo2`, are non-const lvalues, as is the variable you wish to use to store the max, `Foo& foo`. So why do you introduce `const` anywhere? Just leave out `const` from your `max` - although maybe you could rename it `max_lvalue_ref` to make clear what it does.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I wanted to pass const to inform the compiler/programmer they won't change (imagine if we were dealing with a more complex function).

Comment: @AgrimPathak. "they won't change". You mean that `max` will not attempt to change them?

Comment: That could backfire. If `max` takes them by const, then the compiler might assume that `foo1` and `foo2` cannot be modified anywhere in the program. The only time they are referenced is via non-const references, so it seems like a reasonable assumption. The compiler might then make incorrect optimizations, basically assuming that `foo1` and `foo2` are modified nowhere in your program. So if you print values from `foo1` and `foo2` at the end, the compiler might print old (unincremented) values. Perhaps I'm exaggerating, but I suspect that kind of incorrect assumption is allowed by optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues here:

1. Missing const qualifier in result
2. It is dangerous to return reference to const reference parameter

In such case:

```
Foo& foo = std::max(Foo(6), Foo(7));
```

compiler will construct temporary objects for parameters before function call and will destroy them after function call - so you will end up with reference to garbage. Of course if you will always use existing objects it will work - but it is easy to forget about such limitations.

You could remove const from parameters which will resolve both issues and it should be ok for you as you intend to modify object anyway.

Comment: `std::max` returns by `const&`.  And you seem to have missed the question?

Comment: well, at the moment of writing there was an answer without const for arguments which was doing what OP wanted, that why I haven't mentioned it - and it is still a good solution if OP is not using C++11. And yes, std::max returns const& and also dangerous: const Foo& f1 = std::max(Foo(1), Foo(2)); const Foo& f2 = std::max(Foo(3), Foo(4)); f1.f is 4 after second operator here. As OP mentioned classes and don't see why we could not use & instead const& I wanted to warn about this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
T my_max(T&& f1, T&& f2) {
  return std::forward<T>(f1 > f2 ? f1 : f2);
}
```

the above is relatively solid, and will do what you need.  It does require the two parameters to have the same r/l/const ness, which `std::max` does not.  Which is why `max` uses `const&`.

A far more complex version that finds the common reference category can be written, but it can act in surprising ways.

So not be fooled by lack of `&` in return value above: in your use case, the above returns a reference.  If passed rvalues it returns a value.

Here is an attempt at a `super_max` that, if passed lvalues of the same type, returns an lvalue.  If passed two different types, or an rvalue, returns a copy:

```
template<class A, class B>
struct max_return:std::common_type<A,B>{};
template<class A>
struct max_return<A&,A&>{
  using type=A&;
};
template<class A, class B>
using max_return_t = typename max_return<A,B>::type;

template<class T, class U>
max_return_t<T,U> super_max(T&& t, U&& u) {
  if (t < u)
    return std::forward<U>(u);
  else
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

it also only uses `<`, and prefers the left hand side on a tie.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/493bfb3301040e9c)